# Forced Tunneling Express route

Tags: azure, networking, vnet

I want to set up forced tunneling such that all internet destined traffic goes back to on prem through express route.

1 - What&Where do i configure this ?
2 - I am also using Cisco FTD NVA. How will traffic go through NVA first and then to express route?

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for that if Azure has it's own Internet Egress?

How does your setup look like? Do you have a single vnet with an express route gateway attached to it?

Comment: azure vnets have by default a route to internet. So if you want to access internet via on prem firewalls etc you need to route traffic back to on prem via ER.

Comment: afaik, i have to advertise default BGP route to Azure so that internet default route will be replaced. Have anyone implemented this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send traffic destined to the Internet back to on-prem via Express Route you have to make sure you advertise the 0/0 route from on-prem to Azure and in the route table which holds your resources you enable Route Propagation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview